# An algorithm to form non intersecting polygons from set of polygons

Tags: algorithm, graph, maps, triangulation

I have a diagram made of a lot of polygons and each polygons is stored with me in a form of set of points which i can trace to get the polygon.

However these polygons can be intersecting or may contain one another etc.

I want a algorithm to store them to a new set of polygons such that no two polygons in this case intersect or contain one another. Off course they can share boundaries and the diagram should not change but no intersections. Also this set set of polygons should also be stored in form of a list of points i can trace to get the polygon.

Edit : sounds like my question wasn't clear enough so I am adding an example to show what I want.

Refer to the image https://ibb.co/k0x5WF . I had a "red" and a "green" polygon which i have drawn by tracing the points I had stored. The green polygon was inside the red polygon. Now i want to convert it into a blue and a black polygon such that they don't intersect or share "area". they can share boundaries but not area as you can see in the image.

Still haven't received anything so I thought add another example to make my question clear and make sure someone can help.
I have

polygon1 {(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,1)}

polygon2 {(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (1,1)}

I want to convert them into

polygon3 {(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (1,1)}

polygon4 {(1,-1), (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1)}

since they are all closed figures, as long as the cyclic order remains the same, I don't care in what form you give me this result.

Comment: Go to the FAQ sections (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and try to learn how to reformulate your question.

Comment: sounds like you want to find an independent set of a planer graph